# HTML 5 canvas: detect long click

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, web-applications, canvas

I'm working on some HTML5 canvas drawing. The drawing application is an IPad WebApp.

Now I would like to know whether there is any possibility to track a long tap (tap and hold) on the canvas and to link it to an event outside the canvas. For example: I tap hold for three seconds on the canvas, which causes a Popup to be visible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
​<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

You can simply set a Timeout on the `mousedown` event of the canvas,
then clear it on the `mouseup` event.

Here's a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f23ZW/)

```
​var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var timer = null;

​canvas.onmousedown = function(){
  timer = setTimeout( doStuff, 2000 );
};

canvas.onmouseup = function(){
  clearTimeout( timer );
};

function doStuff() {
  alert('hello, you just pressed the mousebutton for two seconds.')
}
```

Comment: This is it thanks. Added an "canvas.onmousemove function(){ clearTimeout(timer);};" To also stop the counter when drawing! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/) and listen to the "hold" event.

Comment: Thanks I will look into this as well, looks quite usefull!